# JavaScript function.subfunction()

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function like this

```
function lib(){
  this.create = function (text){
     return document.createElement(text);
  }
  /* ??? this.attribute = function{} ??? */ 
}
function CreateSomething{
 var x = lib.create('div');
}
```

Now I want another subfunction like .create(), that I can call with. How can I do that?

```
x.attribute('id=Test');
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: @wumm please read properly to know what exactly is the question.

Comment: @C-linkNepal I can't see a single question mark (except in that comment), but maybe you can tell me what the question is. I just see a description of something the OP wants to achieve.

Comment: if I'm reading it correctly you want a function that will add an attribute to x correct?

Comment: You're effectively suggesting adding new methods to a native browser class (`Element`).  It's possible on newer browsers, but older MSIE in particular had issues with it.  I do believe there's one popular JS library that makes extensive use of native object extensions, but I don't recall which one.

Comment: Are you just trying to namespace your functions? any vaguely random 4+letter prefix should suffice for that and it will compile much, much tighter in the Closure Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is pass your newly created element to your `attribute`-function and then return the same element:

```
var lib = {
   create: function (text){
      return document.createElement(text);
   },
   attribute: function(element, name, value) {
      element.setAttribute(name, value);
      return element;
   }
}
```

This would allow you to do both

```
function CreateSomething{
   var x = lib.create('div');
   x = lib.attribute(x, 'id', 'Test');
}
```

or

```
function CreateSomething{
   var x = lib.create('div');
   lib.attribute(x, 'id', 'Test');
}
```

That being said it would just be wrapping standard behavious and you could just as well do this:

```
function CreateSomething{
   var x = lib.create('div');
   x.setAttribute('id', 'Test');
}
```

Comment: Your `lib` object neither has a `.create` nor a `.attribute` method.

Comment: No, now your `library` objects do. Btw, `self` (and returning from a constructor) is completely unncessary. But why don't you just make it a module, instead of a constructor?

Comment: Thank you for the constructive criticism - I've altered my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized this was an error in the OP's original script, not your fault - sorry :)

Comment: No worries. I clearly didn't catch the error myself at first glance, so I'm glad you pointed it out.